# How to filter ip's out of a logfile

Tags: awk, grep

I have a logfile from our apache server and I want to know every unique ip adres that connects to the apache server to /web/Service.

From the example I need the last ip adres and that is in front of localhost.hosting.corp
I think it needs to be done with, grep/awk but i'm not that good with that :)

Below a sample of the logfile, where I replaced the real ip with something else:

````
1.9.2.2 - - [18/Oct/2019:11:53:54 +0200] "POST /web/Service HTTP/1.1" 200 793 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.8810)" "1.2.2.10" localhost.hosting.corp:80
1.9.2.2 - - [18/Oct/2019:11:53:55 +0200] "POST /web2/Service HTTP/1.1" 200 791 "-" "-" "1.2.1.4" localhost.hosting.corp:80
1.9.2.2 - - [18/Oct/2019:11:54:12 +0200] "POST /web/Service HTTP/1.1" 200 793 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.8810)" "1.2.1.7" localhost.hosting.corp:80
1.9.2.2 - - [18/Oct/2019:11:54:38 +0200] "POST /web/Service HTTP/1.1" 200 791 "-" "-" "1.2.1.4" localhost.hosting.corp:80
1.9.2.2 - - [18/Oct/2019:11:54:41 +0200] "POST /web/Service HTTP/1.1" 200 672 "-" "-" "1.2.1.4" localhost.hosting.corp:80```
````

Comment: Please post your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Also your question is NOT clear, which IP address you need in output, so kindly do add sample expected output too in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Using: grep "/web/Service" logfile.txt I do filter out line 2 that has "/web2/Service", so that is part one.
But for me the part that I don't know is how to get then the ip's out of it, that is infront of localhost.hosting.corp:80.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to filter, extract the column before last $(NF-1), strip the '"' (with gensub), and print only the first occurrence (using x[ip])

```
awk '
/\/web\/Service/ {
      ip=gensub("\"", "", "g", $(NF-1)) ;
      if (!x[ip] ) { print ip ; x[ip]++ }
}' log.txt
```

Comment: If I try that I get an error:  
awk: 0602-553 Function gensub is not defined.
 The input line number is 2507. The file is access_log.20191018.
 The source line number is 1.

Comment: Can you check awk version ? do you have gawk ? which Linux ? In general gensub is GNU extension, but is very common. Consider using similar gsub

Comment: This is on AXI 7.1 and I can't find what version it is, I tried multiple options but it doesn't work:
awk -W version
awk -version
awk --version